# Opening and closing connections when using db_query

Tags: php, connection

I'm using this framework that constantly uses `db_query` to query the MySQL server from the PHP code. I'm a bit worried about how it opens and closes the connections and if it may have an impact on the overall number of connections hitting the server. The code is as follows:

```
$sql = "select r.project_id from user_rights r where username = '".db_escape(USERID)."'";

$q = db_query($sql);

$count_i = 0;
while ($row = db_fetch_assoc($q))
{
  $ids[$count_i] = $row;
  $count_i++;
}
$list = '';
foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $list .= 'r.project_id = "'.$id['project_id'].'" or ';
}

return substr($list,0,-3);
```

Comment: Are you using drupal? If not, what framework?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using a research tool called REDCap